# python json.load performs differently on two different system

Tags: json, python-3.x, ascii

I have a json file I am trying to read with python3.6. `text` is one of the keys in the json file and it contains some german text.

I do the following to read the file:

```
import json
file_name='1.json'
file = json.load(open(file_name))
```

When I try to read it on the server in this way I got the following error:

```
>>> json.load(open('1.json'))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/json/__init__.py", line 296, in load
    return loads(fp.read(),
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/encodings/ascii.py", line 26, in decode
    return codecs.ascii_decode(input, self.errors)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 3335: ordinal not in range(128)
```

If I try it as follows I don't get any error but I cannot see the non-ascii characters properly:

```
    file = json.load(open('1.json',encoding='utf-8'))
    file['text']
    "Ich finde, dass dieser Debatte nicht ausgewichen werden darf, auch
 nicht kann", sagte er in der ARD. Die Bundesregierung habe die Kernenergie
 trotz der Verl\xe4ngerung der Laufzeiten um durchschnittlich zw\xf6lf 
Jahre immer als "Auslaufmodell" betrachtet.\nHelfer in Schutzanz\xfcgen am
 Atommeiler Fukushima
```

If I try to open it my local computer I am able to open it without any problem and all the characters appear properly:

```
    file = json.load(open('1.json')
     file['text']
     "Ich finde, dass dieser Debatte nicht ausgewichen werden darf, auch
 nicht kann", sagte er in der ARD. Die Bundesregierung habe die Kernenergie
 trotz der Verlängerung der Laufzeiten um durchschnittlich zwölf Jahre 
immer als "Auslaufmodell" betrachtet.\nHelfer in Schutzanzügen am Atommeiler Fukushima
```

In all of the enviroments, I use python 3.6, my local is osx whereas centos is run on the server. When I check the file format I see it is utf-8:

```
file -i 1.json
1.json: text/plain; charset=utf-8
```

I have 2 questions:

1) Why I get different behaviours with exactly the same code ?

2) How can I fix the problem on the server ?

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was about `LC_CTYPE`. When I set to LC_CTYPE="en_US.utf-8", I started to read the file successfully.